# Why does this use of std::sort with a custom comparator not compile?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I trying to use sort algorithm for sorting the elements of a vector. 
This  is my code snippet.

**Comparator**

```
struct comparator
 {
    bool operator() ( OptVector<pair<int, pair<CgpPop*,CgpPop*> > >::iterator it1, OptVector<pair<int, pair<CgpPop*,CgpPop*> > >::iterator it2)
    {
            return ( ((*it1).first) < ((*it2).first));
    }
} o_comparator;
```

**My Vector**  - Here OptVector is a wrapper over vector which behaves in same manner as standard c++ vector.

```
OptVector< pair<int, pair<CgpPop*,CgpPop*> > > pll_units;
```

**call to sort algo**

```
sort<OptVector< pair<int, pair<CgpPop*,CgpPop*> > >::iterator > (pll_units.begin(), pll_units.end(), o_comparator);
```

But compiler throws following error

```
/calm/svr/sql/generic/stlinclude/stl/_algo.c: In function ‘const _Tp& _STL::__median(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _Tp = _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >, _Compare = comparator]’:
/calm/svr/sql/generic/stlinclude/stl/_algo.c:820:   instantiated from ‘void _STL::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIter, _RandomAccessIter, _Tp*, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIter = _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >*, _Tp = _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >, _Size = long int, _Compare = comparator]’
/calm/svr/sql/generic/stlinclude/stl/_algo.c:841:   instantiated from ‘void _STL::sort(_RandomAccessIter, _RandomAccessIter, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIter = _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >*, _Compare = comparator]’
/calm/svr/sql/generic/source/codegen/cgpop.cpp:1249:   instantiated from here
/calm/svr/sql/generic/stlinclude/stl/_algo.c:78: error: no match for call to ‘(comparator) (const _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >&, const _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >&)’
 /calm/svr/sql/generic/source/codegen/cgpop.cpp:1192: note: candidates are: bool comparator::operator()(_STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >*, _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >*)
/calm/svr/sql/generic/stlinclude/stl/_algo.c:79: error: no match for call to ‘(comparator) (const _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >&, const _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >&)’
/calm/svr/sql/generic/source/codegen/cgpop.cpp:1192: note: candidates are: bool comparator::operator()(_STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >*, _STL::pair<int, _STL::pair<CgpPop*, CgpPop*> >*)
```

Could any one please suggest me what is my mistake ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparator functor is supposed to take the elements but not the iterators as the parameter for comparing.

You should change the parameter type of `comparator::operator()` from iterator to value type:

```
struct comparator
{
    bool operator() ( const pair<int, pair<CgpPop*,CgpPop*> > & lhs, const pair<int, pair<CgpPop*,CgpPop*> > & rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.first < rhs.first;
    }
};
```

<sup>BTW: Making `operator()` const member function is a good habit.</sup>

Comment: Also the call to `sort()` can be shortened to `sort(pll_units.begin(), pll_units.end(), o_comparator);`

Comment: Also, lambdas are part of the language since C++11.

Comment: thanks all ... it worked ... and I also understood the usages in a better way.

Comment: @Leon . could you please explain me why it worked without giving the template argument in sort method. I was having impression that for template method i should provide the type argument.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Because of [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) for template function call.